# Submatrix Indexing and Operations Without Loops

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, submatrix

I'm having the following problem: I have a matrix which is `20 x 1000` and I want to divide it into four submatrices of size `20 x 250`.

After that, I want to make operation to each submatrix assume that I have a vector `P` of length equal to the number of the submatrices, 4.

```
P= [ 3 4 5 6]
```

What I am aiming to do for each submatrix (A) is as follows:

For the first submatrix:   `A(:,1:P(1))=1`

As well as the second submatrix: `A(:,1:P(2))=1` and so on and so forth.

How could I do this without loops?

Comment: Any comments on the approaches mentioned in the only solution presented here?

Answer (score 0):

One vectorized approach could be with a combination of `cumsum` and `bsxfun`, which could be a little memory intensive though -

```
blocksize = 250;
valid_idx = bsxfun(@le,[1:max(P)],P');
idx_mat = bsxfun(@plus,cumsum(valid_idx,2),[0:numel(P)-1]'*blocksize);
A(:,idx_mat(valid_idx)) = 1; %// You can replace this with "A(:,unique(idx_mat))=1;"
```

---

Another slightly different approach -

```
blocksize = 250;
maxP = max(P);
valid_idx = bsxfun(@le,[1:maxP],P');
idx_mat = bsxfun(@plus,[0:numel(P)-1]'*blocksize,1:maxP);
A(:,idx_mat(valid_idx))=1;
```

Please note that to really see the benefits of vectorized solutions, you need to use it when your original loopy code has a lot of iterations going. Otherwise, the overhead associated with the preparatory work to setup vectorized approaches would be a waste. Thus, I am assuming your actual case involves more than just 4 submatrices.

---

Another `cumsum` based approach and this one must be interesting to try out and might even prove to be the best of the lot -

```
blocksize = 250;

%//Get monotonically increasing labels within each group, defined by limits from idx
array1 = zeros(1,sum(P));
grp_starts = cumsum(P(1:end-1))+1;
array1(grp_starts) = P(1:end-1);
grp_labels = [1:numel(array1)] - cumsum(array1);

%// Get offsetted indices
array2 = zeros(1,sum(P));
array2(grp_starts) = blocksize;
offsetted_grp_labels = grp_labels + cumsum(array2);

A(:,offsetted_grp_labels)=1; %// perform the operation(s)
```

Comment: thanks  Divakar for your help... i will try your suggestion and tell you